# What can I do if I already killed a dragon for a Blades quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have just initiated three members into the blades and Esbern gave me my first quest with them to go and 'Kill the Dragon in Skyborn Altar' but I have already killed that dragon and so when we show up there is no dragon to kill.

I have tried using **resetquest BQ04** in the console (BQ04 is the quest ID for the Jarls bounty to kill the Dragon at Skyborn Altar) however this does not work and there is still no dragon there. I do not know the quest ID for this specific quest and haven't seen it online but if I had it I could probably just use the **setstage** command to get past this bug.

Does anyone know what it is or know how I can find out?

Comment: That kind of stupid and obvious bug is exactly what made me quit Oblivion mid-game. Shame on devs.

Answer (score 24):

The altar dragons actually respawn, it just takes some time. Perhaps do some fast traveling, or use Wait (but not at the altar). Many reports are that re-spawning takes 30 in-game days, but I've had locations take only 10.

I just tested Skyborn Altar. 10 days was sufficient for the dragon to respawn. I find it fastest to look at the date on the map screen at bottom right, add 10 for your target, and fast travel the longest distances to pass time. Markarth<->Riften is ~26 hours.

From my experience if you arrive too early you will have to wait all over again, better to load back before the arrival.

Comment: +1 for the early arrival as that will generally reset the counter until the area resets.

Comment: I'll add that respawned dragons will generally *not* give you dragon souls. I reloaded one save probably a dozen times, killing the same dragon over and over, because I was afraid I'd gotten bugged and was worried the lack of a dragon soul was going to cause problems later on. Turns out it was normal though.

Comment: @Kromey Sounds like a bug to me. I kill a dragon, I get a dragon soul. I just tested a few more times at Skyborn Altar, soul each time. :-/

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin I don't know the details but it is definitely normal not to receive multiple souls for static dragon respawns.

Comment: @agf & Kromey, So I went on a dragon slaying tour to all the altars to figure this out.  Each location long since cleared. Many an Ancient Dragon soul was found, until I found some plain Dragons (perhaps spawned much earlier in my game) which didn't decay, no soul. The subsequent respawns though were Ancient Dragons, for which I always received a soul. Somehow level/type based perhaps? Here's an oddity though, the Ancient Dragon at Ancient's Ascent (SW Helgen) never gives me a soul, period, on any respawns. Everywhere else does.

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin Interesting. My conclusion was based on my own experiences (killed that respawned dragon a dozen times, never got a soul), plus the note on this page: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bounty:_Dragon Maybe the note specifically refers to dragons respawned for quests? Or could it be related to the "Cleared" flag -- were the altars where you re-killed the dragons marked as "Cleared" on your map? Shearpoint was definitely cleared on mine (although I hadn't killed Krosis or learned the words there yet -- I killed the dragon and then run away initially, being too weak for Krosis).

Comment: @Kromey They were definitely all marked 'Cleared'. I'm thinking it's something like, "a respawned dragon will not give you a soul" ...... unless you're of sufficiently high level (or finished main quest?) for it to be a high-level spawn such as "Ancient Dragon" which always gives a soul (with Ancient's Ascent bugged). That's only a GUESS. I have no idea. Maybe Ancient's Ascent isn't bugged but spawns a lesser dragon (despite "Ancient" in namesake) that my game considers non-soul-worthy.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a late reply, but the questid is `freeformskyhaventempleb`, and typing

```
setstage freeformskyhaventempleb 20
```

should solve your problem! :-)

Comment: Don't be worried about late replys. It doesn't matter if a question is 2 minutes old, or 2 years old, you should always feel free to answer it. Welcome to the site :)